# How to change Visual Studio exception message language to English while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I am working on machine with XP Dutch version installed on it. Visual studio 2005 is installed in English. I'm having the annoying problem while debugging that all .NET Framework exception message appear in Dutch, which make them really worthless. I tried to change this to English by setting the regional settings in the control panel to US English and then reinstalling the .NET Framework 2.0 (English version) but apparently this did not solve the problem. Does anyone have an idea?

---

I think my question was missunderstood, I don't want to change the current culture of the thread. The problem i'm having is when you are debugging and stepping through the code when suddenly one of those exception windows appears with the exception-message in it.
This exception message appears in Dutch and I would like it to appear English. I hope this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 52):

I did some more research and apparently it is not possible to change the CurrentUICulture by default to a different language then the native language of the installed OS. It can only be changed when doing something like this in the code itself:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Answer (score 17):

**Solved !**

No line of code.

Go to Start > Configuration Panel > Language and region > Administration > Languages for non unicode programs  > Set it to english.

Comment: nothing happened for my case...

Comment: This had no effect. problem is not solved

Comment: Op, is your machine also WinXP?

Comment: It didn't work for me but Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us"); does the trick

Comment: I Already want the locale language to be non-English, besides your duplicated answer on similar questions. -1

Answer (score 8):

This issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/c-exception-messages-in-english). Basically you can change the current thread's [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) to en-US.