# How do I change the language of the Microsoft C# compiler's error messages?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

Their Russian translation is invalid and confusing. E.g. in some messages language keywords were translated. So I want to see the original versions (in #develop, LINQPad, ASP.NET errors etc).

**UPDATE**
This great site helps find original English error messages by their translations: [FindErr.NET](http://finderr.net/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Visual Studio exception message language to English while debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529951/how-to-change-visual-studio-exception-message-language-to-english-while-debugging) or [Prevent exception messages from being translated into the user's language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197127/prevent-exception-messages-from-being-translated-into-the-users-language)

Comment: Read it through carefully. My question has nothing to do with exceptions.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but the accepted answers seem suspiciously related to your problem.

Comment: Yes, they are related, and nothing more.

Comment: So you already tried all suggested solutions and none was working? In what tool do you get these error messages? Also in Visual Studio? What compiler is being used? Looks like you might be using the Mono compiler.

Comment: Suggested solutions are all about exceptions, not compiler messages. I use the Microsoft C# 3 compiler. I have compiler messages in Russian everywhere: in SharpDevelop, LINQPad, ASP.NET etc. I've uninstalled .NET language pack, but it didn't help.

Comment: Change the system language for your machine.  Control Panel + Region and Language.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It doesn't help too. Seems like this settings (I have Windows XP) influence only date, time and money format.

Comment: If nothing can help you may try some brute force. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529464/change-compiler-errors-language-in-visual-studio-2013#comment56947279_22529794

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727 folder.  There should be one or more numbered subdirectories that contains cscompui.dll, the resource file for the C# compiler.  The number is what matters, 1033 is the language id (LCID) for en-US.

Installing the language pack for the .NET framework should fix your problem.  The download for 3.5 SP1 [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=8489ED13-B831-4855-96F7-DD35E4C02A20&displaylang=en), change the Language to get the right one.  The link I gave you ought to be good for English.  If you get a readme.htm then switch the machine back to Russian before you try again.

Comment: I've discovered that I haven't uninstalled the Russian language pack for .NET 3.5. Unlike language packs for other .NET versions it was named in Russian in the Add/Remove programs dialog, so I didn't notice it before.

Comment: I've discovered that the language pack was installed by the presence of the numbered subdirectory 1049 in framework\v3.5, so thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 4):

**Solved !**

No coding ! Go to : Start > Configuration Pannel > Language and region > Administration > Languages for non unicode programs > Set it to english.

It changed error messages language for ASP .Net application that appear in browser. Using Windows 7.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe because my Windows does not support .ultilanguage.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 Users, you can simple change the language of your system in Settings -> Time & Language -> Language -> APP & websites. (You need the desired language packed installed)

Note that this solution may interfere with other apps, but It was the only solution that worked for me.