# Forcing English language exceptions in .NET framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, localization

While working with ASP.NET MVC, I have noticed that exception messages issued by the .NET framework installed on my System are in German. I'd really prefer English messages, so I can post them on SO.

I know this has been asked before on SO, but strangely enough none of the suggested workarounds seem to work in my case. I have already tried the following:

- switching my Windows system to an English locale and restarting Visual Studio
- Setting Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings -> Language to "English"
- setting the thread locale to English right before the exception is thrown as follows:

  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("en-US");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=new CultureInfo("en-US");

  //call my faulty method...

So, how can I make the .NET framework issue English language exception messages? And is there any approach that does this on a per-solution or even system-wide basis?

**Edit:** The exception is thrown while excuting my unit tests. I am not sure if this is the reason setting the thread's culture had not effect.

Comment: If you're configuring Windows options, you may need to restart Visual Studio. Have you tried that? Otherwise, this issue would indeed seem rather odd.

Comment: Yes, I have restared VS  after setting the locale.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Exception messages in English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/c-sharp-exception-messages-in-english)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I just found out, the problem was indeed related to having a different test project. While I have tried setting the UI language to English in my actual project, I did not do the same in the test project, which is why the exception messages were still in German when looking at the test results.

Setting the UI language in the test method right before the exception is thrown did the trick for me.

Comment: You could set the UI language in a Trace point during debugging, so the execution can continue without interruption (for exceptions that don't always appear).  
Set a breakpoint at the line you expect the Exception to be thrown, and have it "print" this message:

`{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");}`

Answer (score 11):

Uninstall the German language pack:

Start - Control Panel - Programs and Functions - Microsoft .NET Framework (4 Client Profile) Language Pack DEU - Uninstall (Deinstallieren)

You may need to repeat the uninstallation for each version of .NET Framework that you find there.

Comment: Agreed. It's useful; it solves the OP:s question in a (slightly different) way, and is definitely useful for the rest of us. I upvoted you to compensate. :)

Comment: Language packs are not longer used, in windows 8 and above .NET uses the language of the OS

Comment: This is the right solution no need for changing thread culture before throwing the exception

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried setting the UI culture to "`en`" in `web.config`? More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the following changes in the web.config and it helped:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
...
```

Comment: Easy, working, and you can remove it during deployment. Thanks, @ADM-IT!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently all the framework exception messages are bound to the installed OS language. So unless you install an English version of Windows The .Net framework exceptions won't appear in English. 
Even though it seems strange that setting the CurrentUICulture to "en-US" does not help, I used this sort of workaround hack to have English messages on my Dutch Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

Actually doesn't exists a good solution for this, vote on Connect for this approach

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591839/exception-localization-in-app-config-and-web-config

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching the culture immediately prior to reading the exception text? It may be that the localization occurs when you access the message - as opposed to when the exception object is created.

Comment: Good point. In my case, the exception is thrown while executing a unit test. I am not sure whether the exception text is read a different thread in this case.

Comment: Could you try setting the current thread UI culture immediate prior to the "string message = ex.Message" code (or whatever you have)?

Comment: The message was read by the test runner. setting the UI language in the unit test method right before the exception is thrown did the trick.