# How to force .NET4 & it's tools to use English for exceptions and other messages

Tags: localization, .net-4.0, installation, locale

I would like for my Win7-x64 **dev box to remain in the current locale (pl-PL)**, but at the same time for **whole .NET tools to run in English locale**.

I previous releases this could be achieved by not installing a language pack add-on that came up in windows update. This time it did sneak up and I cannot find it in windows update history and appwiz.cpl, or it is installed differently.

Can you tell **how to uninstall other than English locales** for .NET installation **or setup .NET & it's tools to use only English locale**?

What **I'm NOT interested** in (and there are already such answers on SO):

- How to setup current process or application locale, within this application (aka. CurrentCulture ). I do want applications I release to use user's current locale.
- Change current thread locale. For the same reason as above.

PS. I would like to avoid re-installation of .NET/VS2010 if possible ;)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092298/force-exceptions-language-in-english

I don't think there is an easy solution.

Comment: @Snake sorry, this is not a duplicate, I do not want to change current process or application locale. I want my VS and .NET tools to behave like there weren't having polish locale instaled, or I want to uninstall polish locale resources.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to get rid of localized messages when you have "localized" version of Windows. Possibly, Windows 7 Ultimate (I am not sure about other versions) should allow changing the whole UI language, and it should do the trick (as this is what CLR uses to determine current locale).

Comment: I want my UI locale to stay theway it is but I'd like the SDK to show up only English messages — translations are horrible, and hard to un-translate when looking for clues while debugging.

Comment: @WooYek: I share your pain, but I am afraid that there is nothing we can do about it. Cheer up, some of the Polish translations are funny :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Polish language pack:

Start - Control Panel - Programs and Functions - Microsoft .NET Framework (4 Client Profile) Language Pack PLU - Uninstall

You may need to repeat the uninstallation for each version of .NET Framework that you find there.

Comment: On W7 I do not have a Language Pack in Programs and Functions nor in the appwiz.cpl list. What should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

For web applications you can put this in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
```