# Force DateTime Format of an Element encoded directly off the model onto the view in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, formatting

I am using delimiters to get the values directly from the model in a data-bound fashion.

I wish to force this format to "**yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss**" on specific values/entries/fields.

There are 2 different lines of code in particular, one being editable and the other not.

Here are the 2 lines:

```
<%: Html.Encode(Model.DateTimeValue)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTimeValue, new { @class = "datetimepicker" })%>
```

How can I force these to comply with the above mentioned format?

I would prefer it if there was an **inline solution** to this.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389187/set-default-datetime-format-c-sharp)

Comment: duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389187/set-default-datetime-format-c-sharp

Comment: The post mentioned sets a global culture. I am looking for an inline solution, so as to have 2 or 3 different formats on a single page if need be.

Comment: An editor template might work for you

Comment: @3dd How would I apply it to the above mentioned code? the normal .ToString("format") does not seem to work.

Comment: for date formatting I used http://www.datejs.com/ using one line of javascript I format the data to the screen. I can post an example if you like tommorow when I'm back at work

Comment: As long as it is an inline code that I can use on the above mentioned lines, it would be greatly appreciated.