# How to disable localization of errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, localization

I use Visual Studio 2008 and it really makes me crazy how it shows error messages (in Error List window, Output window - especially exceptions) partially in English and partially in my native language. Interestingly, it is worse in WPF than in WinForms project. I've read here that it is about Culture of the running thread (so that the problem is in a settings for .NET).

Why am I solving it? It's simple because if I run into an error message and I don't know what it exactly mean or how to fix the problem then trying to google the problem in any other language than in English is very problematic. For example, it would be useful to set English for debugging purposes.

How to solve the problem?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Switch the system language to English as well.  Control Panel + Regional and Language Options.

Comment: It's quite interesting. Warnings display twice - once in my native language and once in English. But errors only in my native language.

Comment: Related, and with a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852569/configure-visual-studio-to-show-error-messages-in-english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked what your VS language settings are & compiler messages are controlled by your OS language settings & what language packs you have installed for the .Net framework...

See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vssetup/thread/f99d14b9-c889-419f-9252-835bec7c7393) for some more information.

Comment: here's the same info, but in [official help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/language)

Answer (score 5):

http://finderr.net/search -- Not entirely an answer but it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes, very useful not only for VS errors but for all error messages found in the logs!