# Visual Studio 2012 - english error messages in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Have installed Visual Studio 2012 Pro on a Windows 8 Pro (Danish).

The problem is that all error messages now are in Danish! I remember that earlier I should just delete the Danish .net framework language pack, but there are not such a package any longer! (Like [Configure visual studio to show error messages in english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852569/configure-visual-studio-to-show-error-messages-in-english)).

So how do I now get English error messages Again?