# Visual Studio returns Dutch exceptions instead of English

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, localization

I have been using Visual Studio on the same Windows machine for years now. Currently 2019
Today I started my computer and exceptions raised are now in Dutch where previously they were in English.

I would like them to be in English once again. 
I have tried the following posts:

- [Configure Visual Studio to show error messages in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852569/configure-visual-studio-to-show-error-messages-in-english) -- but only have ENU installed.
- Checked language settings which are English US
- Checked Tools > Options > Environment - International Settings = English
- Repaired Visual Studio and latest updates

But none of the above made a difference.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this out:
https://ifyoudo.net/post/2019/09/07/how-to-uninstall-a-net-language-pack-for-good

1. Press Windows key + R
2. Type: LPKSETUP
3. Hit Enter
4. Click Uninstall display languages
5. Choose the language then click Next

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the language changed all of the sudden, but you can configure the CurrentUICulture property to "en-US, then you will get english exceptions...

you can try to only change the language when handling exceptions, and then reset it:

```
CultureInfo previousCultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
try
{
  // do something
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // handling exception, writing to log or showing a message
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = previousCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = previousCultureInfo;
```

if this is done a lot, you might want to create a HandlingEnglishExceptionsClass or something.

Comment: Hi @d4zed, thank you for your reply but then my language on screen is also English and parts like currency need to be Dutch

Comment: I edited my answer according to your comment. Your can also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english

Answer (score 0):

Solution for win 11.

Start
--> Settings
--> Time & Language

--> set 'Preferred Language' to the language you need for the exception message

--> Reboot --> then change the keyboard-layout in/over the Taskbar.