# How to create function in c# that will call another function every month and every year

Tags: c#

> my code get an exception that it could not convert the types
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DW3r.png)

```
        static System.Timers.Timer timer;
        public static void schedule_Timer(DateTime scheduledTime)
        {
        
        DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
        //DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15); //new DateTime((nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 8, 42, 0, 0); //Specify your scheduled time HH,MM,SS [8am and 42 minutes]
        if (nowTime > scheduledTime)
        {
            scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMonths(1);
        }
        double tickTime = (double)(scheduledTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
       /*my code fall in the next row*/
       timer = new System.Timers.Timer((tickTime));
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DeleteAllNotUsedTasks);
        timer.Start();
    }
    public static void DeleteAllNotUsedTasks(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ArgamanExpressEntities db = new ArgamanExpressEntities())
        {
            foreach (Dal.Task task in db.Tasks)
            {
                if (task.status == false)
                    db.Tasks.Remove(task);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        timer.Stop();
        schedule_Timer(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));

    }`
```

Comment: What is the error message saying in english?

Comment: @אסתר אליאב - Please, set region language to English before making a screenshots.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve the problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left. If not, please let me know and I'll try to further help you

Answer (score 3):

First, to make your life 100x easier, please refer to [the answers given on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852569/configure-visual-studio-to-show-error-messages-in-english) to understand how to display Exceptions in English.
This change will allow you to Google exceptions and quickly find answers to problems your'e facing.

After you'll make this change, you'll get the following English exception:

> Invalid value '2591982526.9035' for parameter 'interval'.

The reason for this error can be found in
[Timer.Interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netcore-3.1) documentation:

> The time, in milliseconds, between Elapsed events. The value must be greater than zero, and **less than or equal to [MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netcore-3.1)**. The default is 100 milliseconds..

Since `2591982526.9035` is larger than `Int32.MaxValue`, which is `2147483647`, you get an exception.