# System.InvalidOperationException using xaf core with EF and nonpersistent entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

I have the following non persistent entity

```
   [DomainComponent]
   [DefaultClassOptions]
   public class AcmeResult : NonPersistentObjectBase, 
    {
      [Key] public int Id {get;set;}
      // other fields etc
    }
```

In the DbContext I have

```
 public DbSet<AcmeResult> AcmeResults { get; set; }
```

In OnModelCreating I have the following to show there is no table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AcmeResult>().ToTable(null);
```

At runtime I get an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Sequence contains no elements
Source=System.Linq
StackTrace:
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException() in 
/_/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ThrowHelper.cs:line 24
```

The call stack is

```
System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException() Line 24  C#
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITableMappingBase>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITableMappingBase> source) Line 16    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.SelectExpression(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType entityType, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory) Line 172   C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionFactory.Select(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType entityType) Line 794    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateShapedQueryExpression(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType entityType) Line 173  C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression extensionExpression) Line 93    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression extensionExpression) Line 148  C#
    System.Linq.Expressions.dll!System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor visitor) Line 163   C#
    System.Linq.Expressions.dll!System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) Line 35    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query) Line 174   C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query, bool async) Line 72    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDatabase database, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel model, bool async) Line 112    C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 96   C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(object cacheKey, System.Func<System.Func<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>> compiler) Line 76 C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query) Line 92 C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) Line 79  C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>.GetEnumerator() Line 91 C#
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<JT2.Module.Features.Acme.AcmeResult>.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() Line 458 C#
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator<object>(System.Collections.IEnumerable source) Line 23    C#
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<object>.ToList() Line 54 C#
    System.Linq.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<object>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> source) Line 29    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreCollection.Init() Unknown
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreCollection.InnerList.get()    Unknown
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreCollection.Count.get()    Unknown
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.ProxyCollection.Count.get() Line 712  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.SetDataSource(object dataSource) Line 208 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.CurrencyManager(object dataSource) Line 63    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(object dataSource, string dataMember) Line 302   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.this[object, string].get(object dataSource, string dataMember) Line 89 C#
    DevExpress.Data.Desktop.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Platform.Compatibility.DefaultDesktop.DevExpress.Data.Platform.Compatibility.IDesktopBridge.GetListFromBindingContext(object context, object dataSource, string dataMember)   Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Helpers.MasterDetailHelper.GetDataSourceCore(object context, object dataSource, string dataMember, System.Collections.IList existingListSource)   Unknown
    DevExpress.Data.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.Data.Helpers.MasterDetailHelper.GetDataSource(object context, object dataSource, string dataMember)    Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.ActivateDataSource()  Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.DataSource.set(object value)  Unknown
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.XafGridControlDataSourceAdapter..ctor.AnonymousMethod__0(object ds) Line 28   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.ControlDataSourceAdapter.SetControlDataSourceCore(object dataSource) Line 119 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.ControlDataSourceAdapter.SetControlDataSource(object dataSource) Line 116 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.ControlDataSourceAdapter.SetDataSource() Line 90  C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.ControlDataSourceAdapter.TrySetDataSource() Line 80   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.ControlDataSourceAdapter.Control_HandleCreated(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 51 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated(System.EventArgs e) Line 7858 C#
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.OnHandleCreated(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.OnHandleCreated(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 12125   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 13151    C#
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 68 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 122  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll!Interop.User32.CreateWindowExW(Interop.User32.WS_EX dwExStyle, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName, Interop.User32.WS dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, System.IntPtr hWndParent, System.IntPtr hMenu, System.IntPtr hInst, object lpParam) Line 42   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) Line 445  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() Line 4969  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible) Line 5031  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible) Line 5050  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible) Line 5050  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl() Line 4993 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 12858   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 13305    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 1507   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 2093    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 6443   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 6589    C#
    DevExpress.Utils.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.DForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    DevExpress.Utils.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)    Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 68 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 122  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll!Interop.User32.CreateWindowExW(Interop.User32.WS_EX dwExStyle, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName, Interop.User32.WS dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, System.IntPtr hWndParent, System.IntPtr hMenu, System.IntPtr hInst, object lpParam) Line 42   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) Line 445  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() Line 4969  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle() Line 3166 C#
    DevExpress.Utils.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.CreateHandle()   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm.CreateHandle()  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get() Line 2422    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll!Interop.User32.ShowWindow(IHandle hWnd, Interop.User32.SW nCmdShow) Line 16 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(bool value) Line 2316 C#
    DevExpress.Utils.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.SetVisibleCore(bool value)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm.SetVisibleCore(bool value)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show() Line 11320 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinWindow.Show() Line 480 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinShowViewStrategyBase.ShowWindow(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinWindow window) Line 281   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.MdiShowViewStrategy.ShowWindow(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinWindow window) Line 401   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.MdiShowViewStrategy.ShowViewInInspector(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 340    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinShowViewStrategyBase.ShowViewInNewWindow(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 395    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.MdiShowViewStrategy.ShowViewInCurrentWindow(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 409    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewStrategyBase.ShowViewCore(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 90   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.MdiShowViewStrategy.ShowViewCore(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 279   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewStrategyBase.ShowView(DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewParameters parameters, DevExpress.ExpressApp.ShowViewSource showViewSource) Line 134  C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Frame.ProcessActionCreatedView(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs e) Line 199  C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinWindow.ProcessActionCreatedView(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs e) Line 403  C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Frame.ShowViewAction_ProcessCreatedView(object sender, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs e) Line 52   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBase.OnProcessCreatedView(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs e) Line 333 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBase.ExecuteCore(System.Delegate handler, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs eventArgs) Line 194 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.SingleChoiceAction.DoExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem selectedItem) Line 126    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.Binding.SingleChoiceActionBinding.DoExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem item) Line 79 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates.ActionControls.Binding.WinSingleChoiceActionBinding.DoExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem item) Line 37  C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.Binding.SingleChoiceActionBinding.ActionControl_Execute(object sender, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.SingleChoiceActionControlExecuteEventArgs e) Line 68   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates.Bars.ActionControls.BarItemSingleChoiceActionControl<DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem>.RaiseExecuteCore(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem actionItem) Line 31 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates.Bars.ActionControls.BarItemSingleChoiceActionControl<DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem>.RaiseExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem actionItem, bool askConfirmation) Line 96   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates.Bars.ActionControls.BarItemSingleChoiceActionControl<DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem>.RaiseExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem actionItem) Line 89 C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates.Bars.ActionControls.BarButtonItemSingleChoiceActionControl.OnChoiceBarItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e) Line 51    C#
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem.OnClick(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link) Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarBaseButtonItem.OnClick(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem.OnClick(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkClick() Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.OnLinkClick()   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkAction(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarLinkAction action, object actionArgs) Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.OnLinkAction(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarLinkAction action, object actionArgs)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkActionCore(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarLinkAction action, object actionArgs) Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarSelectionInfo.ClickLink(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link) Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarSelectionInfo.UnPressLink(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link)   Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomLinksControl.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)  Unknown
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomPopupBarControl.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) Line 12439    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 13229    C#
    DevExpress.XtraBars.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 68 C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 122  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.UIntPtr dwComponentID, Interop.Mso.msoloop uReason, void* pvLoopData) Line 346  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 1117  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 981    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run() Line 1181   C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.DoApplicationRun() Line 530    C#
    DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v21.2.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.Start() Line 899   C#
    JT2.Win.dll!JT2.Win.Program.Main() Line 74  C#
```

I notice mention of a ProxyCollection

[image: ProxyCollection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can work around this by inheriting from the AcmeResult and using the new class instead.

```
   [DomainComponent]
   [DefaultClassOptions]
   [NavigationItem("Config")]
   [XafDisplayName("AcmeFavorite2")]
    public class Acme2Result : AcmeResult
    { 
       // etc
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177408/why-is-enumerable-count-throwing-invalidoperationexception-for-converting-n) question explained the error