# Localization of error messages

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

When connecting to some of our CRM deployments (**CRM Dynamics 2011**) with an account that exists in the Domain, but wasn't added to the Organization yet, I'm getting an Error message.

This seems alright, although : the error message is in **Chinese**.

[image]

Does anyone know what the language is based on?
Is it a server setting?

I can confirm that the browser and OS settings of the browsing user are not in Chinese. Neither is the OS of CRM server.

I can also confirm that the **Base Language** of this deployment is set to English.

[image]

### Edit

It seems that installing a language pack overrides the default localization of error messages. I have reproduced this on a development server.

Could this be a bug in Dynamics?

Comment: Traditional Chinese Language Pack is or was installed? the user was added before to the organization and after removed? Language of the server?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Chinese Language Pack has been installed at some point. I can get this confirmed though. The user was never added to the org. Server language is English.

Comment: Could it be possible that the latest installed language pack overrides the default error message localization?

Comment: I've just installed the Chinese lang pack on a local CRM server, and indeed : the error messages are defaulting to Chinese. This feels like a bug in CRM to me?

Comment: The infrastructure team confirmed that the Chinese language pack is probably the last pack they installed. The only other language pack (other than the 2 Chinese ones) installed is the Spanish one.

Answer (score 0):

The language is Traditional Chinese, I guess the CRM organization belongs to a customer from Hong Kong.

the message is:

```
商業管理錯誤
與目前紀錄有關的使用者識別碼無效
```

is the standard error message when a user doesn't belong to the organization:

[image]

and the url is in this form:

> https://[server]/_common/error/errorhandler.aspx?BackUri=&ErrorCode=0x80041D1F&Parm0=%0d%0a%0d%0aError%20Details%3a%20The%20user%20Id%20is%20invalid.&RequestUri=%2f[OrganizationName]%2fdefault.aspx

I think the base language of this CRM is Traditional Chinese, so you get the message in the base language.

Comment: It's a CRM deployment, located in the US. Where can I configure this base language?

Comment: The base language is decided when the organization is created, and is not possible to change after. You can check the base language inside CRM from File -> Options -> Languages

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot of the base language. It's set to English!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the "base" language of CRM is set or used, but I know languages are User specific.  This allows different users to see different, language specific labels on the same form.

I'd first verify what the language of the user is that you're attempting to login with (you'll have to do an SDK call since you can't get logged in, or assign them to an org, then look at their language settings within CRM)

I'm guessing that's just a .Net Error that's created on the CRM server itself, using the standard [.Net method of determining what language to create the exception method i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/c-sharp-exception-messages-in-english)n.  Somehow the user context of the user that is running the CRM site got changed...

Comment: I have done that. If I add the user to CRM, his settings are all defaulted to English, our timezone, etc. Even users that have never been in CRM are defaulted to Chinese, although none of their user settings (nor in the browser, nor in the operating system, nor in anything) ever had Chinese in them. I also confirmed that installing a language pack changes the language of those error messages, so I'm convinced that the error language is not based on a user-specific setting, but on a server setting.

Comment: Ah...  I guess that makes sense.  When you through an exception, there isn't any way of specifying that you want this error message displayed for this language vs another.  So all errors are now in Chinese since you installed the language pack, for all users?  I'm wondering if the language of the CRM server, or the user that runs the CRM site affects the exception messages...

Comment: I would guess it would show the error messages in either the users browser localization (if that language is available), or alternatively in the CRM base language. You can have multiple language packs installed, it seems really weird to me that it picks a language, based on which pack you installed last. The CRM server language doesn't seem to affect the error messages. Neither does the user that's trying to log on. I think it's time to ask our MS premier support engineer to jump in here.