# how to change .net error message language to english

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

I am using VS2012, .net 4.5 and Win7 Professional. Win7 is Turkish and now I am getting error messages in Turkish! In Win7 Professional it is not possible to install/uninstall language pack. Is it possible to change the error message language without reinstalling VS or .net pack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me:

Start > Configuration Panel > Language and region > Administration

In the tab "Languages for non unicode programs", choose English.

You also have the option to set the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the part of code where you are debugging / logging. Just play a bit with Globalization settings, something like:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

or

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Goodluck!

Comment: I tried both solution, unfortunately no change. I should say that the error messages caused by SQL Server 2012 are in Turkish but the other ones, for example "Index out of range", are in English. I set SSMS to English with "SET LANGUAGE English" command and now in management studio I get errors in English. However inside vs2012 they appear in Turkish. I could not get the point.

Comment: The first solution you offer makes .net originated error messages English. For sql server originated errors, i changed the default language of db user. Whole solution is this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked, had been struggling with it myself a while back. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn´t work for me. What did work was changing the Site setting in IIS. Select the Site on IIS Manager, click on ".NET Globalization"
[image: iis manager site settings]

... then change UI Culture to English:

[image]