# Get .net6 build message in english?

Tags: .net

when i build some code, the build messages that are logged in the build windows are in my own foreign language, which is not english.

This makes it very hard to google them, especially for new technologies like maui.
Any way to get them in english ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Check this:
[Similar error messages probelm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005210/how-to-change-net-error-message-language-to-english)

Comment: @AdlerBalduran Nope. The answer you point at is for older versions of the product and no answer are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a workaround:

Rename the "fr" folder (check your 2 letter language) to anything else in:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android`
in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS`