# My language in terminal is Polish. How do I change it to English?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It occurs only in 'problems' section and only while I am using C#

I tried to change the display language to en, but it was already like that. I also tried to use a command to change cultureinfo to en-US, but I haven't seen any results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change .net error message language to english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005210/how-to-change-net-error-message-language-to-english)

Comment: @user That question is about VS2012 and this one is about visual studio code.

Comment: Yes, but I presume the error message comes from underlying build tooling and not from the IDE itself. VS Code is highly built on top of extension infrastructure. If VS Code _itself_ is the source of this problem, I'll eat my sock. You just need to figure out how to configure the underlying build tooling that your C# development extension is pulling these messages from.