# I want to see System Messages in Diff language

Tags: c#, .net

I tried searching a lot for internationalization of custom messages but made me more and more confused.

What I need is just one small thing.

Currently when I write following lines,

```
int i = 5;
int j = 10 / (i - i);
```

it gives me exception in English. Even by throwing DivideByZero Exception in English like "Attempted Divide By Zero".

I just want this message in some other language i.e hi-IN culture.

I do have Hindi language installed in my OS as well. I tried changing Culture, UICulture everything. None are working.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/c-sharp-exception-messages-in-english

Comment: Have you installed the .NET framework language packs? (localized exception messages are part of the .NET framework language packs)

Comment: @road242: Is Windows Language pack for Hindi and .Net Language pack for Hindi different?

Comment: I think so but I don't know if Hindi is supported, see language packs at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-Us/download/details.aspx?id=40751

Comment: @road242: You were right dear. Its working now.