# How to get Win32Exception in English?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm trying to get all `Exception` messages in English, no matter what language is the machine my program running on.

I've manage to get almost all exception messages in English using answers from the following posts:
[Exception messages in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/c-sharp-exception-messages-in-english)
and some other solution I've found (like using reflection to change the default `CultureInfo`). 
I have specific problem with `SocketException`, No matter what I'm doing I'm getting it in the default machine's language.

I've created a test program to show the problem:
This test program will print Exceptions in default language:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //I'm not listening on the following port:
                TcpClient s = new TcpClient("localhost", 2121);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                //the following file doesn't exists:
                File.ReadAllText("filenotexist.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This result on my machine the following text:

```
H:\Shared>Test-def.exe
Socket exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2121
File exception: Could not find file 'H:\Shared\filenotexist.txt'.
```

On Japanese machine it write all exceptions in Japanese (which I don't understand):

```
Z:\>Test-def.exe
Socket exception: 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。 127.0.0.1:2121
File exception: ファイル 'Z:\filenotexist.txt' が見つかりませんでした。
```

(The Japanese '\' looks different in Japanese machine, but when copied to my machine it shown as '\')

So from combining of the answers I've found, I've implemented the following solution, so now it looks like this:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        //will change CultureInfo to English, this should change all threads CultureInfo to English. 
        public static void SetEnglishCulture()
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            //change CultureInfo for current thread:
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

            //change CultureInfo for new threads:
            Type t = typeof(CultureInfo);
            try
            {
                t.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultCulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
                t.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultUICulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                t.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultCulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
                t.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultUICulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
            }
            catch { }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //first thing: set CultureInfo to English:
            SetEnglishCulture();
            try
            {
                //I'm not listening on the following port:
                TcpClient s = new TcpClient("localhost", 2121);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                //the following file doesn't exists:
                File.ReadAllText("filenotexist.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now on Japanese machine it write the file exceptions in English but the Net.socket exceptions are still in Japanese:

```
Z:\>Test-en.exe
Socket exception: 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。 127.0.0.1:2121
File exception: Could not find file 'Z:\filenotexist.txt'.
```

I've also tested some other exceptions, some exceptions are now shown in English, but not all of them, the socket exceptions are persistent. As you can see, the file exception had been translated to English, but the socket exception is still in Japanese.

I've tested it in almost any .NET framework (from 2.1 to 4.5) still the same.

- Is there a complete solution for all the exceptions?
- Did I missed anything?
- Should I do anything else?
- Maybe there's other way to run program on foreign machine, and set some environment variable, to get English output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution so I'll upload it here in case someone will need it.
If anyone have a better solution I'll be happy to know so please comment.

In case of `Win32Exception`, we can use `FormatMessage` and translate the error code to both English and default languages, and replace the default by English. 
If I take the English without replace, I lose the parameters. so in case the replace failed I'll return the Exception With additional description in English.

Here's my full solution:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCulture
{
    class Program
    {
        static void SetEnglishCulture()
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Type type = typeof(CultureInfo);
            try
            {
                type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultCulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
                type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultUICulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
            } catch { }
            try
            {
                type.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultCulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
                type.InvokeMember("m_userDefaultUICulture", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, ci, new object[] { ci });
            } catch { }
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint FormatMessage(uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, uint dwMessageId, uint dwLanguageId, StringBuilder lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr Arguments);
        public static string Win32ExceptionInEnglish(Win32Exception ex)
        {
            const int nCapacity = 820; // max error length
            const uint FORMAT_MSG_FROM_SYS = 0x01000;
            const uint engLangID = (0x01<<10) | 0x09;
            const uint defLangID = 0x0;
            StringBuilder engSb = new StringBuilder(nCapacity);
            StringBuilder defSb = new StringBuilder(nCapacity);
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MSG_FROM_SYS,IntPtr.Zero, (uint)ex.ErrorCode, defLangID, defSb, nCapacity, IntPtr.Zero);
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MSG_FROM_SYS,IntPtr.Zero, (uint)ex.ErrorCode, engLangID, engSb, nCapacity, IntPtr.Zero);
            string sDefMsg = defSb.ToString().TrimEnd(' ','.','\r','\n');
            string sEngMsg = engSb.ToString().TrimEnd(' ','.','\r','\n');
            if(sDefMsg == sEngMsg) //message already in English (or no english on machine?)
            {
                //nothing left to do:
                return ex.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = ex.Message.Replace(sDefMsg,sEngMsg);
                if (msg == ex.Message)
                {
                    //replace didn't worked, can be message with arguments in the middle.
                    //I such as case print both: original and translated. to not lose the arguments.
                    return ex.Message + " (In English: " + sEngMsg + ")";
                }
                else 
                {
                    //successfuly replaced!
                    return msg;
                }
            }       
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            SetEnglishCulture();
            try {
                // generate any exception ...
                const int notListenningPort = 2121;
                new TcpClient("localhost", notListenningPort);
            }
            catch(Win32Exception ex)//first try to cach win32 Exceptions
            {
                Console.WriteLine("W32 Exception: " + Win32ExceptionInEnglish(ex));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)//this fit to the rest .NET exceptions which affected by CultureInfo
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " +ex.Message);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any english text, neither in VS2008 (.net 3.5) nor in VS2015 (.net 4.5.2). defSb contains a german text, engSb contains nothing.

Comment: defLangID  is Language Identifier, I used eng-us in my sample, but looks like your machine not support it, but maybe it support other eng. language? maybe eng-uk ? You can try to use other locale, see full list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A `SocketException` is a `Win32Exception`. Like all other classes that derive from `Win32Exception`, it gets its message from Windows using `Win32Exception.GetErrorMessage(int error)`, which uses [`FormatMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) in Kernel32.DLL.

In doing so, the message effectively comes from Windows, not from .NET. Windows will return a message in the Windows display language, and AFAIK, there is nothing you can do about that from within your .NET program.

Comment: I've found (And uploaded in edit) a solution for the issue, Your comment was very helpful. Thanks again. If I could I've up-vote you again! (I Just realized I can up-vote on other of your answer...)

Comment: Nice idea but Win32Exception.GetErrorMessage(int error) returns the localized text as already present in Message property

Answer (score 1):

You may have to wrap the line that prints error to console in a separate thread that has locale set to english because the Framework exception code loads the error messages from its resources based on the current thread locale.
here is what i am talking about in a bit of code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

    try {
        TcpClient c = new TcpClient("localhost", 1234);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // thread that logs exception message to console
        Thread logger = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(PrintException));
        logger.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        logger.Start(ex);
    }


}

private static void PrintException(object ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ((Exception)ex).Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? The message is not loaded by the framework, but by Windows. It does not come from .NET resources. And the message is set in the exception at construction time. I doubt that reading the Message property on a thread that has set the en-US culture will automatically translate the Japanse text in there to English.

Comment: I changed the `CurrentCulture` in my code for all the threads, it didn't help. the additional thread may help just if you want to keep both languages.