# Configure NLog to write exception messages in English

Tags: .net, logging, ninject, nlog, currentuiculture

Is it possible to configure NLog to write the exception messages in English and not in the current thread culture?

It is probably possible to work around this issue by switching the current thread culture as proposed here [Exception messages in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english) but I don't want to do it if there is another solution.

My loggers are exposed as Ninject ILogger so I could also implement each methods and change the thread culture, but again if there is another solution I prefer to avoid that.

Comment: See also on GitHub: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/172

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution with some help. See [github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/172](http://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/172) thanks to Julian

It is possible to write a custom WrapperLayoutRenderer that switches the culture before the exception is logged.

```
namespace NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers
{
    [LayoutRenderer("InvariantCulture")]
    [ThreadAgnostic]
    public sealed class InvariantCultureLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
    {
        protected override string Transform(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }

        protected override string RenderInner(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                return base.RenderInner(logEvent);
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It must be registered before any logger is created

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers.RegisterDefinition("InvariantCulture", typeof(InvariantCultureLayoutRendererWrapper));
```

And can be used like that in the config

```
layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${InvariantCulture:${exception:format=tostring}}"
```