# Change language of exceptions that pop up in the screen visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual studio 2015 I get the exception messages that pops up on the screen (while debugging) in french I want to change it to English do you have an idea of how I can do that?

Comment: My guess that you (or windows update) installed a language pack for .net. There are [hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english), but the best to uninstall the language pack.

Comment: But i can't find it there is no language pack for .net in the controle panel.