# Play WAV file from NAudio on discord

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, discord, naudio

What I am trying to is, build a bot that wil play an wav file (that I pull from somewhere else) inside a discord channel. I thought let's use a library called NAudio which has a nuget packages that includes everything inside.
But I cannot get it to work. (for mp3 it works perfectly)

I made a sample on this [Github page](https://github.com/LightFuryTeam/SpeechToDiscord)

So I read that I need to go to a **PCM Stream** to convert it to a valid format for discord. But for some reason **it doesn't play... (Also it doesn't give any error to go from).** But when I use NAudio to play the PCM Stream it just works.

```
private async Task SpeakAsync(IAudioClient client)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("Audio/Test123.wav"))
        {
            var naudio = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader);

            //using (var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
            //{
            //    waveOut.Init(naudio);
            //    Log.Logger.Debug("Playing sounds...");
            //    waveOut.Play();
            //    while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            //    {
            //        Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //    }
            //}

            var dstream = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Music);
            await naudio.CopyToAsync(dstream);

            dstream.Flush();
            client.StopAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error(e, "Error while sending to discord");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what is in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611921/discord-net-cant-stream-audio-with-naudio). But that didn't help...

Comment: If mp3 works, try converting the wav to mp3 first. Hacky but might work.

Comment: @Flutterish Good idea and also simple. That I didn't think about trying that. It is an extra conversion step but better then nothing...

Comment: @Flutterish I will try it...