# CultureInfo("en-US") does not convert the exception message to English

Tags: c#, exception, cultureinfo

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But `ex.Message` is still shown in Chinese. How can I fix it?

Comment: The `message` of most exceptions is set on construction (not all, but most). Changing the culture after catching the instance generally won't change it; it would need to have to be changed before.

Comment: Why do you expect such behavior? You should set the culture before exception raised

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception messages in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english)